# Atom takes much time to compile typescript files for angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, atom-editor

I am working on the Angular 2 RC-6 from [Angular2 Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/). I find atom too slow to compile my '.ts' files. If I move my tsconfig.json from root folder to any other directory, it compiles fast but **misses some DI such as 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'.**

Please suggest how to make atom compile fast, or any modification on the tsconfig.json.

My project directory structure is as instructed in documentation.

Here is my tscongig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  }
}
```

Comment: It's likely that TypeScript is trying to search too deep into certain folders to look for `.ts` files. Try explicitly including files, or using the `exclude` field in `tsconfig.json`. If you're using TypeScript 2, there's also an `include` field you can use.

Comment: thanks, now it is quite fast.

Comment: As a heads up, in 2.0 I believe we'll be excluding `node_modules` by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like Daniel said you just need to exclude a few folders. Mainly the `node_modules` folder, since there are tons of TypeScript and Javascript files in there.

You can do so by adding the following `exclude` option to your `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
]
```

Adding this to your current config it would look like this:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: **Thanks!**  This greatly enhanced the *processing speed*.  I am surprised that *Angular Tooling* is still available even though the files are *excluded*.  Do you know how/why this is possible?

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks the compiler for me. Atom 1.12.9, Atom-Typescript 10.1.13

Comment: also wanted to point out that doing that exclude will remove typings.  so, make sure to add "!node_modules/@types" to that

Comment: Oddly enough, as others here are reporting, I get full type support even without re-including @types (so just using the config in the answer)

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this here in case anyone else has the same issue as me.

I tried excluding the *node_modules* folder as suggested in rinukkusu's answer but this ended up breaking the compiler altogether (Atom 1.12.9, Atom-Typescript 10.1.13).

After some hair pulling I added the *include* option to see what would happen. The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) doesn't specifically say that both are required but it seemed to fix the problem.

So in my case the config would look like this:

```
 {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false
    },
    "include": [
        "app/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
}
```